# store data in array laravl

Tags: php, laravel

public function ad(Request $request)

{

$products = $request->session()->get('cart');

foreach ($products as $product) {

Faktor::create([

```
'user_id' => Auth::id(),
'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
'name' => $product['name'],
'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
'price' => $product['price'],
```

]);

}

return redirect('bill');

}

when i show invoice to user , it is a invoice include one user name and one user mobile and many products . how i can show invoce without foreach with foreach for each id show one invoice

id user_id product_id name price
1 1 2 ssd 1000
2 1 1 i9 gen12 1000

@ foreach($invoice as $item)

{{ $item->user->name }}

{{ $item->name }}

{{ $item->price}}

thank you for your help

or How i can store data in array

Comment: 'product_id' =>  $product['product_id']

Comment: -->ERROR: Undefined array key "product_id"

Comment: $products = $request->session()->get('cart'); foreach($products as $product){ $pid=$product->product_id;}

Comment: in controller ?                                                                                                  $products = $request->session()->get('cart');                                                                                            
         foreach($products as $product)
        { $id=$product->product_id;}

Comment: my Error is in controller that it cannot get  product_id

Comment: Undefined array key "product_id"

Answer (score 0):

**Solution !**

```
Faktor::create([

'user_id' => 1,

'product_id' =>  $req->get('product_id'),// here solution

'total' => 1,

]);

return redirect()->back();
```